# Override SwaggerConfiguration in JH4.x

Tags: jhipster

How can I override the Docket bean from [jhipster SwaggerConfiguration](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/config/apidoc/SwaggerConfiguration.java)?  I need to add custom Docket::directModelSubstitute for my api.

Answer (score 3):

To override SwaggerConfiguration I added SwaggerConfig class to my project config/apidocs that extends SwaggerConfiguration and @Override the swaggerSpringfoxDocket bean

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig extends SwaggerConfiguration {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwaggerConfig.class);

    @Bean
    @Override
    public Docket swaggerSpringfoxDocket(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
```

Finally add SwaggerConfiguration to the exclusion for @EnableAutoConfiguration in App.java

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class, SwaggerConfiguration.class})
```

It would be a lot easier if SwaggerConfiguration had @ConditionalOnMissingBean for the swaggerSpringfoxDocket bean.